# Can't retrieve entity config: chrome_extension/chromeextension

Tags: magento-1.9

I have been creating magento extension using MySql4 approach. Today I was trying with new approach (as I understand EAV approach).
All working fine but cannot call `model->collection` at all. I have searched everywhere but no luck. Basically followed this [link](http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-install-install-upgrade-data-and-data-upgrade-scripts/).

**digitalcinema/chromeextension/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <DigitalCinema_ChromeExtension>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </DigitalCinema_ChromeExtension>
</modules>

<frontend>
    <routers>
        <chrome_extension>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>DigitalCinema_ChromeExtension</module>
                <frontName>chrome_extension</frontName>
            </args>
        </chrome_extension>
    </routers>

    <layout>
        <updates>
            <chrome_extension>
                <file>DigitalCinema_ChromeExtension.xml</file>
            </chrome_extension>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>

<global>
    <blocks>
        <chrome_extension>
            <class>DigitalCinema_ChromeExtension_Block</class>
        </chrome_extension>
    </blocks>

    <helpers>
        <chrome_extension>
            <class>DigitalCinema_ChromeExtension_Helper</class>
        </chrome_extension>
    </helpers>

    <models>
        <chrome_extension>
            <class>DigitalCinema_ChromeExtension_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>chrome_extension_resource</resourceModel>
        </chrome_extension>
        <chrome_extension_resource>
            <class>DigitalCinema_ChromeExtension_Model_Resource</class>
            <etities>
                <chromeextension>
                    <table>chrome_extension</table>
                </chromeextension>
            </etities>
        </chrome_extension_resource>
    </models>


    <resources>
        <chrome_extension_setup>
            <setup>
                 <module>DigitalCinema_ChromeExtension</module>
            </setup>
        </chrome_extension_setup>
    </resources>

</global>

<adminhtml>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <chrome_extension_options>
                                        <title>XML Generate for Chrome Extension</title>
                                    </chrome_extension_options>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</adminhtml>

<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <chrome_extension before="Mage_Adminhtml">DigitalCinema_ChromeExtension_Adminhtml</chrome_extension>
                    <frontName>chrome_extension</frontName>
                </modules>
            </args> 
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>

<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <chrome_extension>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>*/1 * * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>chrome_extension/observer::importProduct</model>
            </run>
        </chrome_extension>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
</config>
```

**DigitalCinema/ChromeExtension/Model/Chromeextension.php**

```
class DigitalCinema_ChromeExtension_Model_Chromeextension extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('chrome_extension/chromeextension');
    }
}
```

**DigitalCinema/ChromeExtension/Model/Resource/Chromeextension.php**

```
class DigitalCinema_ChromeExtension_Model_Resource_Chromeextension extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('chrome_extension/chromeextension', 'chromeextension_id');
    }
}
```

**DigitalCinema/ChromeExtension/Model/Resource/Chromeextension/Collection.php**

```
class DigitalCinema_ChromeExtension_Model_Resource_Chromeextension_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('chrome_extension/chromeextension');
    }
}
```

**DigitalCinema/ChromeExtension/sql/chrome_extension_setup/install-1.0.1.php**

```
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$table = $installer->getConnection()
    ->newTable($installer->getTable('chrome_extension'))
     //******** 
     //********I should use $installer->getTable('chrome_extension/chromeextension')) but this also gives me same error.
     //********
    ->addColumn('chromeextension_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'identity'  => true,
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'primary'   => true,
        ), 'Id')
    ->addColumn('type', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR, null, array(
        'nullable'  => true,
        ), 'Type')
    ->addColumn('filename', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR, null, array(
        'nullable'  => true,
        ), 'File Name')
    ->addColumn('path', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR, null, array(
        'nullable'  => true,
        ), 'Path')
    ->addColumn('time', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP, null, array(
        'nullable'  => true,
        ), 'Time')
    ->addColumn('store_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
        'nullable'  => false,
        ), 'Store ID')
    ->addIndex($installer->getIdxName('sitemap/sitemap', array('store_id')),
        array('store_id'))
    ->addForeignKey($installer->getFkName('chrome_extension', 'store_id', 'core/store', 'store_id'),
        'store_id', $installer->getTable('core/store'), 'store_id',
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE,
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE)
    ->setComment('XML For Chrome Extension');

$installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);

$installer->endSetup();
```

**DigitalCinema/ChromeExtension/controllers/IndexController.php**

```
class DigitalCinema_ChromeExtension_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $t = Mage::getModel('chrome_extension/chromeextension');//->getCollection();

       $d = $t->getCollection();
       var_dump($d);
       echo get_class($t);

    }
}
```

**DigitalCinema/ChromeExtension/helpers/Data.php**

```
class DigitalCinema_ChromeExtension_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

**Not sure if I need `setup` file too**

This giving me **Can't retrieve entity config: chrome_extension/chromeextension**.

I am not sure what is missing/typo or anything. As I understand my mistake is somewhere in `resourceModel` section.

`echo get_class($t);` in **Indexcontroller.php** prints `DigitalCinema_ChromeExtension_Model_Chromeextension`
and `var_dump($t)` returns:

```
object(DigitalCinema_ChromeExtension_Model_Chromeextension)[90]
  protected '_eventPrefix' => string 'core_abstract' (length=13)
  protected '_eventObject' => string 'object' (length=6)
  protected '_resourceName' => string 'chrome_extension/chromeextension' (length=32)
  protected '_resource' => null
  protected '_resourceCollectionName' => string 'chrome_extension/chromeextension_collection' (length=43)
  protected '_cacheTag' => boolean false
  protected '_dataSaveAllowed' => boolean true
  protected '_isObjectNew' => null
  protected '_data' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected '_hasDataChanges' => boolean false
  protected '_origData' => null
  protected '_idFieldName' => null
  protected '_isDeleted' => boolean false
  protected '_oldFieldsMap' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected '_syncFieldsMap' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
```

Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the line of code that results in "Can't retrieve entity config: chrome_extension/chromeextension."? is kind of unclear from your question? is it this one: `$d = $t->getCollection();` ?

Comment: yes, that's right and I can see you have pointed typo in your answer, I will correct it tomorrow. All day wasted not finding typo, poor me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a tag `<etities>` in your `config.xml`.
It should be `<entities>`. You are missing an `n` in here:

```
        <etities>
            <chromeextension>
                <table>chrome_extension</table>
            </chromeextension>
        </etities>
```